# AWS CodeCommit fails to authenticate via ssh after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy)

Tags: openssh, aws-codecommit

I just upgraded my desktop to Ubuntu 22.04. When I attempt to push to one of my git repos on AWS CodeCommit (using ssh) I get:

```
$ git push origin master
Unable to negotiate with 52.94.226.180 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I try the same thing on a computer that uses the previous version of Ubuntu, using the same keys and ssh configuration, the push succeeds:

```
$ git push origin master
[master 879fbb1] -
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100755 Blah.pdf
To ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my_repo
   e360ec8..879fbb1  master -> master
```

I added `HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` to the entry in `~/.ssh/config`, so it looks like this:

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
  User XXXXXXXX
```

Now I get a different error:

```
$ git push origin master
APKAIKOVHJDF7L22TRPA@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Maybe this might help?

```
$ sudo scanssh -s ssh 52.94.226.180
52.94.226.180:22 SSH-2.0-AWSCodeCommit VGh1LCAyOCBBcHIgMjAyMiAyMDozOToyMSArMDAwMFRE84lk14QcsWNrhwqxNLNmRuhBFhi2T0uc9R+6yS0sQklQWVZaOGpobGJHYWdvUER3MHhUVTYzY3c5SzlXSEFNOTRYNWdKMW0yY3M9
Effective host scan rate: 1.02 hosts/s
```

Comment: This is happening on Azure DevOps as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the line `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa` as well to your entry to your `~/.ssh/config`, so it looks like this:

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
  User XXXXXXXX
  HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

##### More Information about the issue:

Ubuntu 22.04 ships with a new version of ssh (OpenSSH8.9p1), while the previous ubuntu versions used OpenSSH8.4p1 or older.

There is a breaking change in OpenSSH8.8p1 which disables RSA signatures using SHA-1 Hash algorithm by default.

From [OpenSSH Release Notes](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8)

> This release disables RSA signatures using the SHA-1 hash algorithm
> by default. This change has been made as the SHA-1 hash algorithm is
> cryptographically broken, and it is possible to create chosen-prefix
> hash collisions for <USD$50K [1]
>
> For most users, this change should be invisible and there is
> no need to replace ssh-rsa keys. OpenSSH has supported RFC8332
> RSA/SHA-256/512 signatures since release 7.2 and existing ssh-rsa keys
> will automatically use the stronger algorithm where possible.
>
> Incompatibility is more likely when connecting to older SSH
> implementations that have not been upgraded or have not closely tracked
> improvements in the SSH protocol. For these cases, it may be necessary
> to selectively re-enable RSA/SHA1 to allow connection and/or user
> authentication via the HostkeyAlgorithms and PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms
> options. For example, the following stanza in ~/.ssh/config will enable
> RSA/SHA1 for host and user authentication for a single destination host:
>
> ```
> Host old-host
>     HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
>     PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
> ```
>
> We recommend enabling RSA/SHA1 only as a stopgap measure until legacy
> implementations can be upgraded or reconfigured with another key type
> (such as ECDSA or Ed25519).
>
> [1] "SHA-1 is a Shambles: First Chosen-Prefix Collision on SHA-1 and
> Application to the PGP Web of Trust" Leurent, G and Peyrin, T
> (2020) https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/014.pdf

Comment: Everyone says to add this to your `~/.ssh/config`. What if there is no config file? Because this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @DanielPrzybylski Then you create one. It is quite inconvenient to not use one at least with AWS, hence [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html) For Azure you will need to adapt the contents.